# Identity Column does not follow sequence number id on delete

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
Create table DocumentMaster
(
DocID int Identity(1,1) not null Primary key,
DocName varchar(30) UNIQUE not null
)
```

When i insert a record in it everything work fine but if i delete a record or an error is came when i try to insert a duplicate records in DocName column "a DocId does not follow a sequence number pattern "

```
DocID   DocName
1        Doc1
3        Doc2
```

(Expected DocID 2 but its 3 when tried to insert duplicate value in DocName)

Please help it out

Thanks

Comment: If you care about the numeric values of identity columns, you're using them wrong. You should treat them as opaque blobs that happen to fit inside numeric columns.

Comment: Can you provide full script of your actions (include error message) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of primary key definition.
one of the important rule of primary key is to it maintain unique inside whole database.
Identity specification tries to hod this rule. 
for example if you delete an identity row which has referenced in other table , database consistency should be maintain.
so if a row inside identity was deleted or badly inserted, the effort of that row shouldn't be inside db. so the next is selected.

Comment: Can u please provide me a query to maintained consistency